# How do I load extension on firefox and safari browser?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, safari-extension, firefox-developer-tools

I have developed extension for chrome and later I made browser specific using gulp.

So I know left with folders.

```
/Chrome
/Firefox
    |-/data/
    |-/locale/
    |-index.js
    |-package.json
/Safari
```

So for the chrome it was simple drag and drop.

So problem I faced is when I try to load on firefox browser at [about:degugger](http://about:debugger) it would reject my extension saying it is corrupt.

For Safari I searched on their website and I found documentation for only using Xcode editor.

Answer (score 3):

**Install unpacked extension on Safari**

1. Open Safari
2. Go to menu `Develop->Show Extension Builder` (If there is no `Develop` menu, open Safari `Preferences->Advanced`, and check `Show Develop menu in menu bar`)
3. In Extension Builder window, click `+` at the left-bottom of the window, then click `Add Extension`
4. Select your extension folder (Your extension folder should be named as `YourExtName.safariextension`)
5. Now your extension will show at left panel of Extension Builder, you can click `Install` button to install it

**Install unpacked extension on Firefox**

Latest version of Firefox support load temporary extensions (Not sure from which version).

Steps:

1. Navigate to about:debugging
2. Click `Load Temporary Add-on` button
3. Select manifest file of you extension

Comment: Steps for `Firefox` works, but `Safari` seems to not be able to load extensions anymore.

Comment: Reference about `Safari`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370551/show-extension-builder-absent-in-develop-menu-in-safari-13?newreg=e3f0106eaa1a4bd1aa301240b8c254c7

Answer (score 0):

**Safari**

1. Open the Gallery by choosing Safari Extensions from the Safari menu.
2. Click “Install now" next to the extension that you want to install.

You can also get extensions directly from your favorite developers. When you download an extension from a developer, you get a file that ends with .safariextz. Double-click the file to install the extension. It isn't signed or hosted by Apple, so Safari asks you to confirm that you trust the source and want to install the extension.

**Firefox**

You need to enable the debug mode check more information [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/23/loading-temporary-add-ons/)

Comment: u didn't get my question right.
I asked for how to test or load extension on sarafi and firefox not the ready-made extension to install.

By the way thank you for your response on this question.