# how to install addon i developed on safari?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari, add-on

Sooo... I made my first extension and I managed to run it on Chrome and Firefox with no problems. Now I am trying to see how to install it on safari and I fount [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension) link. Is it really such a different process from the other two browsers or am I missing somenthing?

Comment: Safari implements it differently. Nothing weird, Apple often does that.

Comment: @wOxxOm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868296/how-do-i-load-extension-on-firefox-and-safari-browser i just found this but i do not seem to have the 'Show Extension Builder' options in safari.... I'm lost...

Comment: Uhm, what you found is not about WebExtensions. When I google for "safari webextensions" here's the link that comes at the top: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions